# refresh chart in access

Tags: charts, refresh

in access how can I refresh a bar chart in form automatically when I change data from another form and the two forms are in tab control page0 and page1

I want to refresh the chart when moving from page1 to page0
in access :
Tables:

- tblPoints
  -PointID
  -PointValue
  -PointDate
  -stdID

-tblStudents
-stdID
-stdName
-stdClass
-Photo
Queries:
-qrytop10
-qrytopten
-qryTotalbyclass
Forms:
-Dashboard: there a control tab with page0 in it frmqrytop10 and page1 in it frmStudents
-frmqrytop10
-frmStudents
-frmStudents2

how to automaticaaly refresh the chart in frmqrytop10 when moving from page1 to page0.. vb code